# Django TestCase not saving my models

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I'm currently writing some tests for a Django app. I've got the following standalone function in my app's signals.py file:

```
def updateLeaveCounts():
   # Setting some variables here
    todaysPeriods = Period.objects.filter(end__lte=today_end, end__gte=today_start).filter(request__leavetype="AN")
    for period in todaysPeriods:
        print period
        counter = LeaveCounter.objects.get(pk=period.request.submitter)
        # some Logic here
        period.batch_processed = True
        period.save()
```

and in my TestCase, I'm calling it as follows:

```
def test_johnsPostLeaveCounters(self):
    # Some setup here
    p = Period.objects.create(request=request,start=datetime(today.year,today.month,today.day,9),end=datetime(today.year,today.month,today.day,16,30),length='whole')
    updateLeaveCounts()
    self.assertEqual(p.batch_processed,True)
```

`updateLeaveCounts()` is catching my newly created Period object in the for loop (I can see its details printed to the console by `print period`), but my assertEqual() test is failing - telling me that the batch_processed attribute is still False.

It's as if the `period.save()` transaction isn't being called.

I'm aware that in Django versions prior to 1.8, you'd have to use the TransactionTestCase class, but I'm running 1.8.3 for this project at the moment, so I don't believe that's the issue.

Is there something I need to do to have the TestCases correctly reflect the `model.save()` action I'm performing in this function and hence have this function covered by tests?

Comment: This is nothing to do with tests. `p` is simply not the same object as the one saved in `updateLeaveCounts`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to use [refresh_from_db](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.refresh_from_db):

```
# ...
updateLeaveCounts()
p.refresh_from_db()
self.assertEqual(p.batch_processed, True)
# ...
```

Comment: Thanks Vladimir! Do you know if there's a reason why this isn't done automatically when using the test framework? I couldn't see this documented anywhere in the Django docs.